# Subsetting rows in data.table where one column is not NA and the values in a list of other columns have exactly one NA

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("A", "B", "C")
dt <- data.table(A = c(NA,10,20,15),
                 B = c(30,10,5,15),
                 C = c(40,10,NA,15),
                 TOTAL = c(75,30,30,45))
```

```
    A  B  C TOTAL
1: NA 30 40    75
2: 10 10 10    30
3: 20  5 NA    30
4: 15 15 15    45
```

I would like to select all rows where only one value is missing for `A`,`B`, and `C` and where the value for `TOTAL` is available. So in that case that would be row number 1 and 3. To keep it more general I would like to use the character vector `cols`.

I tried to do the following:

```
dt[!is.na(TOTAL), rowSums(is.na(.SD)) == 1, .SDcols = cols]
```

But ideally I would like to subset the rows in i like this:

```
    A  B  C TOTAL
1: NA 30 40    75
2: 20  5 NA    30
```

and then compute the NAs in j as TOTAL minus available columns:

```
    A  B  C TOTAL
1:  5 30 40    75
2: 20  5  5    30
```

Does Someone have an idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First calculate the difference between `TOTAL` and the sum of each row. Then in those rows where there is only one `NA`, set the `NA` to that value.

```r
cols <- c("A", "B", "C")
dt[,
    diff := TOTAL - rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE),
    .SDcols = cols
][dt[!is.na(TOTAL), rowSums(is.na(.SD)) == 1, .SDcols = cols]][,
    (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(is.na(x), diff, x)),
    .SDcols = cols
][, diff := NULL][]

#        A     B     C TOTAL
#    <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     5    30    40    75
# 2:    20     5     5    30
```

#### Update in response to question in comments

If you want to get the full data table back, create the `diff` column only for those values where there is one `NA` and only replace values in the rows where `diff` is not `NA`.

```r
dt[dt[!is.na(TOTAL), rowSums(is.na(.SD)) == 1, .SDcols = cols],
    diff := TOTAL - rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE),
    .SDcols = cols
][!is.na(diff),
    (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(is.na(x), diff, x)),
    .SDcols = cols
][, diff := NULL][]
```

Comment: Thank you. That works exactly as I wanted. What does \\(x) exactly do? It's the first time I see it.

Comment: It is shorthand for an anonymous function since R 4.1. It is identical to writing `lapply(.SD, function(x) fifelse(is.na(x), diff, x))`.

Comment: @98198128 if you've seen the `~ .x` type of thing before, it's very similar to that

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I was wondering if it is also possible to update the values and get the full data table back?

Comment: @98198128 see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Use `pacman` to install (if necessary) and load `dtplyr` and `tidyverse`
2. Use `lazy_dt()`, so we can use `dtplyr` on the data.table
3. Find rows where the number of `cols` NA columns is 1, and `TOTAL` isn't `NA`
4. Create a `r`emainder column (`TOTAL` minus `cols` columns).
5. For all `cols` columns, if it equals NA, then replace it with `r`.
6. Drop `r` column

Code:

```
pacman::p_load(dtplyr, tidyverse)

dt |>
  lazy_dt() |>
  filter(rowSums(across(all_of(cols), is.na)) == 1,
        !is.na(TOTAL)) |>
  mutate(r = TOTAL - rowSums(across(all_of(cols)), na.rm = TRUE),
         across(all_of(cols), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), r, .))) |>
  select(-r) |>
  as.data.table()
```

The data.table call:

```
`_DT91`[rowSums(data.table(A = is.na(A), B = is.na(B), C = is.na(C))) == 
    1 & !is.na(TOTAL)][, `:=`(c("r", "A", "B", "C"), {
    r <- TOTAL - rowSums(data.table(A = A, B = B, C = C), na.rm = TRUE)
    A <- fifelse(is.na(A), r, A)
    B <- fifelse(is.na(B), r, B)
    C <- fifelse(is.na(C), r, C)
    .(r, A, B, C)
})][, `:=`("r", NULL)]
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C TOTAL
1:  5 30 40    75
2: 20  5  5    30
```

Comment: The way `dtplyr` decomposes this is actually quite interesting - it seems to create two copies, i.e. `data.table(A = is.na(A), B = is.na(B), C = is.na(C))` and `rowSums(data.table(A = A, B = B, C = C), na.rm = TRUE)`. I wonder why it does this - feels like it wouldn't be as fast as but I think there must be a reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @SamR it seems like it is because I used `across` twice, (though I guess in retrospect I could have potentially have used it just once. Not super familiar with data.table best practices (hence using dtplyr haha), but if I were to speculate, I'd say dtplyr seems it might be a bit declarative, but perhaps dtplyr's intuition isn't that great when it comes to more complicated `across` + `mutate` calls

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve your problem (require `R 4.3.0` or a more recent version):

```
dt[rowSums(is.na(dt[, ..cols]))==1 & !is.na(TOTAL),] |> 
  _[, sm := rowSums(.SD, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols=cols] |> 
  _[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, fcoalesce, TOTAL-sm), .SDcols=cols] |> 
  _[, sm := NULL][]

#        A     B     C TOTAL
# 1:     5    30    40    75
# 2:    20     5     5    30
```